# getting value from list of combo box

Tags: php, arrays, combobox

I have a list of combox box that I generate on runtime on the basis of number of rows.If there are 5 rows there are 5 combo boxes.
I have a submit button on the bottom and I want that when I click on submit It should sae the updated value in database.In php we get value from  a combo box `<select name="cc"></select>`
with `$_POST['cc']`,But now I have each combo box, so my problem is

- Giving different name to each combo box (might use an array
- Getting value from the set of combo boxes.
  Any one who can help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cc[] as the name and in PHP your going to receive an array with all the info.
Or maybe you can just append a number after each name and interate them to read all results.

```
<select name="cc[]">...options...</select>
<select name="cc[]">...options...</select>
<select name="cc[]">...options...</select>
```

then in PHP $_POST['cc'] should be an array with all the selected options.